# How to NFC scan without refresh in android?

Tags: android, webview, tags, nfc, ndef

I'm trying to NFC tagging in android.
My activity has a webview and its set url in onCreate().
When NFC tagging, NDEF infomation can be fetched normally, but page address is not maintained.

how can i solve it?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    this.webview = findViewbyId(R.id.webview);
    this.webview.loadUrl("https://www.abcblarblar.com/");
    this.nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == intent.getAction()) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        ...
    } 
}
```

The manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.NFCActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (because you show no code on how you are reading the NFC tag) that you are using `enableForegroundDispatch` ?

This method Pauses your App while the Android OS reads the NFC Cards.

If this is the cause there are two possible solutions:-

1) Make sure your Application handles being paused and saves it's InstanceState (as there is a chance it might be killed and restarted) or you are doing something in `onResume` that is causing this.

2) Use `enableReaderMode` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle) to read the card, Because with this way of reading a NFC card your application does not get Paused, instead the callback is created in separate thread in your App

Comment: appreciate @Andrew
I write enableForegroundDispatch () and confirmed the URL is maintained.